# Python multiple commands tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im quite new to python and cant solve a problem after searching a lot. Maybe you guys can help me out. I want to add multiple commands to 1 butten. So if you have 100hp, you will lose every time 10hp and if you are on 0hp you get 50hp back, but dont know how to do that. I have read you need to use 1 function and inside both functions but when im doing that i get an error.

```
player_1_lose_10_Button = Button(self, text = "10 HP", command=self.myfunction)
    player_1_lose_10_Button.place(x=180,y=140)

def myfunction(self):
     lose10(self)
     check(self)

def check(self):
    global player1health
    if player1health <= 0:
        player1health +=50
        player_1_lose_10_Button = Button(self, text = "50 HP", command=self.check)        
        print('You died, you get 50hp back')

def lose10(self):
    global player1health
    player1health-=10
    print(f'You lost 10 HP, current HP: {player1health}')
```

Comment: I edited out syntax errors and added traceback you should have included originally.  It is pretty self explanatory.  The error appears to not be in the code posted.  Before posting, you should fix trivial syntax and name errors yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine these into one function just fine:

```
def lose_but_check(self):
    self.lose10()
    self.check()
```

Comment: I get this: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmet\OneDrive\Desktop\Troep\ts.py", line 47, in lose_but_check
    lose10()
NameError: name 'lose10' is not defined

Comment: Put lose_but_check *after* your other functions. Python is picky about order, as it is trying to go through the code just once.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, but im trying the whole day to find the error but cant still find it.. I still get the same error if i put the lose_but_check function after the other functions

Comment: So, are these actually class methods? Could we see the class?

Comment: Yes, used class window

Comment: Could we see the everything put together? The problem is that I can run some of the code, sort of, and it works fine. We can't see your actual full context, so it's hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: I was testing it on lose10 so if i press on 10, it will decrease hp and if it hp becomes to 0 it will go to 50 again. I

Comment: Sir, i thank you so much for helping me out. I can now work forward to finish my project for school. I appreciate it... :D